# Installing an APK on /system/priv-app

Tags: android, installation, system, android-external-storage, android-7.1-nougat

I have a rooted TV Box with Android 7.1.2 which didn't come with the `Files` app (`com.android.documentsui`), so I can't give write access to external drives.

I tried the following steps to install `DocumentsUI.apk`:

- move `DocumentsUI.apk` to `/system/priv-app/DocumentsUI/DocumentsUI.apk`
- `chmod 744 /system/priv-app/DocumentsUI`
- `chmod 644 /system/priv-app/DocumentsUI/DocumentsUI.apk`
- `chown 0.0 /system/priv-app/DocumentsUI`
- `chown 0.0 /system/priv-app/DocumentsUI/DocumentsUI.apk`
- `chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /system/priv-app/DocumentsUI`
- `chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /system/priv-app/DocumentsUI/DocumentsUI.apk`
- reboot

Even so, when I try to launch the app, it always force closes with the following error message on logcat:
`Neither user 10072 nor current process has android.permission.CACHE_CONTENT`

Any idea if I'm missing something?

Please note I'm not on Android 8+ so as far as I know I don't have to add an XML on `/system/etc/permissions`.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this thread on the Kodi site that might help.  https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=308040&page=2

Short version: Since you are rooted find */data/system/packages.xml* and */data/system/packages.list*

Now you should find your package name in packages.list and then edit packages.xml

Find the apps section you want (e.g. com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander),

```
locate its <perms> section and add the following line:
<item name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" granted="true" flags="0" />
```

Have a look at the Kodi thread if something I've type is unclear.  Hope this helps,

Chris.

Answer (score 2):

`CACHE_CONTENT` permission has protection level signature:

```
<!-- @hide Allows an application to cache content.
     <p>Not for use by third-party applications.
     <p>Protection level: signature
-->
<permission android:name="android.permission.CACHE_CONTENT"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Putting your app in `/system/priv-app` isn't enough. It also needs to be signed with the same key used to sign the platform (as it's Android's platform that defines that permission).

AFAIK there's not an easy answer here. You need to integrate the unsigned APK into the Android build system as a prebuilt (or if you have the source, as regular app), and build your own Android dist and flash that.

Comment: Any idea if I can circumvent the problem otherwise? Giving write access to external devices directly, I mean, without the need for launching DocumentsUI

Comment: I not not familiar with the functionality of that app. Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to download some content to a USB HDD. Normally, applications demand the permission for write access as in [this flow](https://plus.google.com/+KrzysztofG%C5%82odowski/posts/7C18qDBoYP4).  However, I can't get past the "Grant" button

Comment: This is getting out of my understanding, sorry. This thread https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=304517 seems to indicate you can write to the drive but it needs to be at a well-defined path. Starting an app to request permission to do something is an odd workflow.